# how to attach a String variable to an email

Tags: android, string, email, variables, android-studio

In Android Studio I wish to send an email on a button click. I am using the following code till I work out what is going on before I start changing thing.

```
    String[] TO = {"ABC@yahoo.com.au"};
    String[] CC = {"xyz@gmail.com"};
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email subject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some message added in here");

    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        finish();
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This works fine and well and shows up on my phone with the email content being as expected, however the email content, "Some message added in here" line is clearly hardcoded. I obviously wish to add in my own content by doing the following

```
    String content = "Information I want to send";
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
```

But for some reason the email content is blank. Why does is a string "content" recognised but a String variable x is not?

Comment: Can you please put the complete activity code?

Answer (score 2):

Check This Examples
By Looking at your code i only found problem in setting

1. emailIntent.setType(text/plain).
2. May Be you are using Gmail for sending mails(So you have to check second example).

**Send Email (to Phone Email Client)**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "some@email.address" });
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

**Send Email (to Gmail)**

Gmail does not examine the extra Intent fields, so in order to use this intent, you need to use the Intent.ACTION_SENDTO and pass a mailto: URI with the subject and body URL encoded.

```
String uriText =
    "mailto:youremail@gmail.com" + 
    "?subject=" + Uri.encode("some subject text here") + 
    "&body=" + Uri.encode("some text here");

Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);

Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
sendIntent.setData(uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send email"));
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OPs question. I'm interested to know why he has the problem too, and how to fix it...

Comment: @iaindownie i have mentioned what he is doing wrong. Is it sufficient

Comment: The second example worked very well, thanks muchly. However though you mentioned what I am doing wrong, it doesn't explain why it is wrong.
String x = "hello world" and "hello world" are both strings. Why does one work and not the other

Comment: @gavin it is based upon app to app what kind of way they are using for communicating with other apps most of app prefer universal way that is first example and some apps have their own rules that's it.